# Adding fields to Cloudwatch without using JSON

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

So I have typical run of the mill logs from Nginx and tomcat servers which are just single line text files with typical log format.  I have changed the tomcat access logs to output pipe delimited fields so I can easily process them using some unix scripts.  I'd like to get rid of my unix scripts and move to using cloudwatch to process my logs in a similar manner, however I found out that cloudwatch really doesn't understand anything beyond timestamp, message, and logstream by default.

It will add fields using JSON, but JSON is verbose when it comes to log files.  I'd like to just let it process a CSV file which seems like an obvious alternative to JSON.  I'm willing to change my log format to meet a requirement like that, but I can't find any information about how I could do that.

Is my only option to translate my logs into JSON in order to add fields to cloudwatch?  I am aware of the parse command, but I find that cumbersome to reconstitute my fields every time I want to build a query.  Especially since these will mostly be access logs which will have numerous fields.  I have aws cloudwatch log agent setup on my systems and I'm currently sending these logs to cloudwatch.

Comment: CloudWatch doesn't have the concept of a schema, so I doubt anything like CSV would be supported. Also see [Supported Logs and Discovered Fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html).

Comment: The format of the arbitrary JSON defines the schema in that all JSON objects will have the same layout hence that shared layout IS the schema.  Otherwise you couldn't reasonably query across all objects of different schemas.  And if you can take in arbitrary JSON then CSV is just a simpler format of the same thing.  The header is the metadata defining the columns, and each row is an object where the keys are the header, and the columns are the values.  How hard is that and given that a majority of log files are much closer to CSV than JSON in their native formats.

Comment: CloudWatch doesn't take whole log files. It takes chunks with a handful of rows in them. It also doesn't require that all JSON objects have the same layout. I don't know how hard it will be with their set of limitations, but that's just what they chose to do.

Comment: I guess my point is that translating a CSV-like structure into a JSON object would be trivial.  And awslogs-agent could support translating typical logs into JSON if it just knew the column layout.  So the point of me asking about this is does this exist in awslogs-agent that I'm unaware of?  Or is there some other piece of infrastructure that can translate my run of the mill logs into something that Cloudwatch would recognize without me rolling my own solution?  The answer to those questions seems to be no, and sort of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing there is to handling space delimited log files is to use Metric Filters.  Or at least that's how the authors of CloudWatch designed it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

The best examples of this is here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/ExtractBytesExample.html

Not sure if this is going to work for what I'm trying to do with logs, but it's a start.  And it's the closest thing to a proper answer.  If you want it done right, you gotta do it yo'self.